# Explanation of the filter timing analysis in FPGA

Tags: fpga, filter, vhdl, timing-analysis

I have wrote a FIR filter in VHDL by using ISE design suit. In design summary I can get all information about the timing analysis.

There is information about the max frequency.

[image]

and I have also found information about gate delay.

What does minimum period( max frequency) mean for filter realisation?

Comment: That means it's a very slow filter, that's the fastest you can clock it for reliable operation. If you need higher clock rates you'll need to improve the pipelining.

Comment: @user_1818839, improve the pipelining or use a faster FPGA part.

Comment: @TonyM when it's this bad, a faster FPGA won't be much help. Sure, if you get 80MHz and need 100MHz for example, that's an option.

Comment: @user_1818839, oh yes it will, make a huge difference, far more than +25%. For example, if you have a MAX 10 or iCE40 and switch to a Virtex-7 or UltraScale, you'll find a huge speed difference. And there's loads of parts between and around those extremes. We don't know what the OP is using but my statement stands, whatever FPGA they have as it's clearly not top-end.

Comment: @TonyM I thought you were referring to speed grades. Sure you could replace a $10 Spartan-6 with a $1000 Ultrascale and get several times the speed, but that's still the wrong answer for something as basic as an FIR filter running as glacially slow as 11 MHz.

Comment: @user_1818839, that's not my answer - not meaning $10->$1000 was covered by "*And there's loads of parts between and around those extremes*" which you're not reading, for some reason. This is lurching around pointlessly and fussily. Either change the logic circuit or use faster technology. Oh, like: *if you need higher clock rates you'll need to improve the pipelining or use a faster FPGA part*. Done.

Comment: @user_1818839 about 86 Mhz, is it still slow filter?

Comment: @TonyM  about 86 Mhz, is it still slow filter?

Comment: In a modern FPGA, 86MHz is pretty slow and I'd be looking for architectural improvements IF it didn't meet my goal... In a Spartan-3 it would be reasonable.

Comment: @user_1818839 what is the best frequency I can reach? I am working with a multiplier-based filter implementations . I can make some correction in adder part...but it doesn't increase the max frequency ( max 105Mhz)

Answer (score 2):

Your filter is a synchronous design with a clock. Assuming you have provided the timing constraints correctly, the *minimum clock period* or the *maximum clock frequency* is the maximum frequency (as reported by the Synthesiser) at which you can clock your design and guarantee reliable operation (ie., with no [timing violations](https://vlsiuniverse.blogspot.com/2017/02/setup-and-hold-violations.html#:%7E:text=If%20a%20timing%20path%20is,Increasing%20clock%20skew)) on the FPGA you have chosen.

Beyond this clock frequency, the operation of your design is not guaranteed to be reliable, as it may cause timing violations.

Comment: frequency , about 86 Mhz, is it still slow filter?

Comment: Report says 86 ns or 11 MHz. That's slow for digital filter.

Comment: Minimum period: 11,613ns (Maximum Frequency: 86,110MHz) ( my result). How to improve it?

Comment: You should ask it as separate question. Not in comments. Besides you don't acknowledge the answers given by this community by not accepting answers and as well as you delete the questions once someone answer it. Which is not a welcoming behaviour here.